# Socket.io listening on multiple ports?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've did some searching and couldn't find any updated answers about this topic, seeing as the answers found applied only to older versions of Socket.io.

Here is my code:

```
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(7000, '::1', function () {
    // Now listening
});

io.on('connect', function (socket) {

}
```

Am I able to add in additional code? such as:

```
http.listen(8000, '::1', function () {
    // Now listening
});

io2.on('connect', function (socket) {

}
```

I want this single node.js instance to be listening on two different ports at once. This is so that I can handle two different types of clients appropriately, by having them connect to their appropriate socket, and then handling the two groups differently.

How would one do this?

Comment: Have you considered doing namespaces in `socket` That is customer still connects to a specific port but they go to a seperate namespace?

Comment: @SamuelToh Sorry I don't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure one HTTP instance can not listen to multiple ports. You should try something like:

```
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connect', function (socket) {

});

http.listen(7000, '::1', function () {
    // Now listening
});

let http2 = require('http').Server(app);
let io2 = require('socket.io')(http2);

http2.listen(7001, '::1', function () {
    // Now listening
});

io2.on('connect', function(socket){

});
```

By the way, I think you can handle multiple different types of clients with a single socket by making them join different namespaces. From socket.io documentation:

https://socket.io/docs/#restricting-yourself-to-a-namespace

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

Comment: Looks like ardilgulez forgot to change http to http2 in the second instance

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what `app` is, assuming you are using the popular `express` server module. Yes, it is possible to do.

What you could do is by getting the main NodeJS process to spawn `2 express servers`. Each listening on a specific port. Then have 2 sockets each binding to a server.

**Note:**
There is a major downside in this kind of design as you never know how many more customers you might possibly have in the future. You can possibly continue to duplicate the code to spawn `n` number of server and sockets but you'll eventually run out of ports to bind.

That is assuming your business grows extensively. 1 option is to look into namespaces within a socket. If you're happy to discuss, let me know hwne you have open a new topic on it.

**Example:**

*Server:*

```
global.appRoot = require('app-root-path');

var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();

var server1 = app.listen(7788, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + server1.address().port);
});

var server2 = app.listen(5566, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + server2.address().port);
});

var socket = require('socket.io').listen(server1);
var socket2 = require('socket.io').listen(server2);

socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log("hi socket 1");
});

socket2.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log("hi socket 2");
});
```

*Client:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.1/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
            var socketClient1 = io('ws://localhost:5566');
            var socketClient2 = io('ws://localhost:7788');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

> Server listening on port 7788
>
> Server listening on port 5566
>
> hi socket 1
>
> hi socket 2

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this, in socketio.js file,

```
var port;

if(!process.argv[2] || isNaN(process.argv[2]))
{
    port = 3030;
    console.log('Port is not set. Default port 3030 is applied');
}
else
{
    port = process.argv[2];
    console.log('port is set to ' + port);
}

/**
 * Start Listening For Socket IO Connection Requests
 *
 */
http.listen(port, function ()
{
    console.log('Socket IO listening on port : ' + port);
});
```

Can run socket IO server like this, with your specific port

```
node socketio.js 3035
```

or normally with no specified port

```
node socketio.js
```

this way you have many socket IO server instances running, as you wish. Hope this will help some one.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var express =   require("express");

    var app =   express();

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
     console.log("Inside app get  method");

    });

    app.listen(2000,function(){
        console.log("Server is running on port 2000");
    });

    app.listen(2001,function(){
        console.log("Server is running on port 2001");
    });
```